# Getting an 404 because of wrong domain running laravel in docker under wsl2

Tags: laravel, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I've been developing for Laravel using Homestead (VirtualBox and Vagrant) on Windows 10. Recently I wanted to switch to Docker and the Linux Sub System on Windows (WSL2).

Under Homestead I've been running my app under my-domain.test. In my `docker-compose` file I use localhost on port 8008. I can access the website under localhost:8008 but I get an 404 on every single page I want to access. Inspecting the links, Laravel seems to use my old domain `my-domain.test` for every link generated. So instead of creating links like `localhost:8008/xyz` it generates links like `https://my-domain.test/xyz`.

Of course I've updated my `.env`file, cleared the (config) cache, cloned a complete new copy of my repository and set up the project in a complete new directory within the sub system. I've also uninstalled all pieces of Vagrant, VirtualBox and Homestead.

I've searched the complete project for references on the old domain. I havn't found anything.

On an other system it works. Somehow my current system seems to hang on the old domain..

How can I achieve this without reseting my whole computer?

This is my `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  pdbv1-db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: pdbv1-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    tty: true
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pdb
      MYSQL_DATABASE: pdb
      MYSQL_USER: pdb
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pdb
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - ./docker-db:/var/lib/mysql

  pdbv1-backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - WITH_XDEBUG=true
        - USERID=$UID
    env_file:
      - .env
    user: $UID:$GID
    container_name: pdbv1-backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: pdbv1-backend
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=Docker
    working_dir: /var/www
    ports:
      - "8008:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score -1):

There's 2 ways to look at this:

1. go with my-domain.test
   add that domain to your windows hosts file and point that to 127.0.0.1
   Also check the dockerfile of your nginx and check your nginx conf file for your domain
2. the laravel code. check in your .env file for the url, is that localhost or my-domain.test?
   Then look in the entire sourcecode for my-domain.test
   and of course in the database itself as well.

(Edit: I see that you've already done that, but it would be the only explanation)

Frankly I would go with option 1: you will have your my-domain.test back and you can use multiple domains / multiple projects.
I only use localhost for quick stuff and for managing my database and my redis.